# On a Remote Event Receiver, how to copy file from one document library to another?

Tags: remote-event-receiver

I'm working on a remove event receiver which when triggered by an ItemDeleting event should copy the list item (file) from the original document library to another.

Please see a code below for reference:

```
private void HandleItemDeleting(SPRemoteEventProperties properties)
{
    using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateRemoteEventReceiverClientContext(properties))
    {
        if (clientContext != null)
        {
            var documentLibraryName = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle;
            var documentLibraries = clientContext.LoadQuery(clientContext.Web.Lists.Where(l => l.Title == documentLibraryName));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var documentLibrary = documentLibraries.FirstOrDefault();

            if (documentLibrary == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            var archiveDocumentLibraryName = properties.ItemEventProperties.ListTitle + " - Archive";
            var archiveDocumentLibraries = clientContext.LoadQuery(clientContext.Web.Lists
                .Where(l => l.Title == archiveDocumentLibraryName));
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            var archiveDocumentLibrary = archiveDocumentLibraries.FirstOrDefault();

            if (archiveDocumentLibrary == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            //** insert code here to copy file (item) from documentLibrary to archiveDocumentLibrary **//
        }
    }
}
```

> Note that the purpose of the code above is to help illustrate the
>   problem and can be modified as long as it solves the original intent of
>   copying the file triggering the event to another document library.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several techniques you could use, and lots of examples on the web...

CSOM:  do a web search for "csom copy file from library"

REST web services: do a web search for "SharePoint REST copy file from library"

.NET file upload classes: use the WebClient, or other classes, to upload the file to a URL.

Comment: Thanks for your post. Do you have any experience working with any of the "techniques" mentioned? Can share any code?

Comment: There are many examples of each technique on the web. Here's one REST call that moves the file and its metadata: /sites/Site1/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Documents')/items(8)/file/moveto(newurl='/sites/Site2/Documents/yourDocument.docx')